# How can I keep a solid background behind text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, overprint

I have a problem with small text on a green background. After separating the black plate text solid background is missing.

[image]

I need the green background to be solid so that there is no overlap when printing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your text is selected and in your attributes panel, select "Overprint Fill".

[image]

Comment: Just a quick correction.. If you are in CMYK color mode, your colors do not need to be spot colors to be able to select overprint fill.  They have to be spot colors in RGB color mode to be able to select overprint fill.  No need to thank me.  Just give my answer an upvote : )